# Looking for an appropriate synchronization mechanism

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, mutual-exclusion

Presume I have the following (pseudo) code:

```java
class Cache {
    Entry addIfMissing(String data) {
        // omitted for brevity
    }
    void evictOldEntries() {
        // omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

```java
class Program {
    private Cache cache = new Cache();

    doWork() { // called from multiple threads
        var entry = cache.addIfMissing("omitted for brevity");
        // work with entry
    }

    static {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            cache.evictOldEntries();
        }, 10, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

I want to make sure while the `evictOldEntries` method is running all the other threads in the program have to wait for it to be done.

Which synchronization mechanism would be appropriate in such a scenario?

Comment: `I want to make sure while the evictOldEntries method is running all the other threads in the program have to wait for it to be done` -- That is a **lock** or **mutex**.

Comment: And if your question is "how do I suspend all other threads while evictOldEntries is running," you don't have to do that; you just have to make sure that evictOldEntries is not running when doWork is called.  There are ways in java to see if a lock has been acquired.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I still want to be able to execute `doWork()` in multiple threads concurrently, I just don't know how. If I use a lock only one thread can be inside `doWork()` at once, no?

Comment: Yes, that's how a lock works.  Your problem is not getting your threads to get in line behind doWork; it is blocking doWork while evictOldEntries is executing.

Comment: Okay, but I am trying to circumvent exactly that scenario. You are right, when evictOldEntries is running no thread should be inside `doWork`. But I want multiple threads to be in `doWork` concurrently. Hence, I think locks aren't appropriate.

Comment: @JohnReese why do you think that your set-up warrants no locks? Please explain

Comment: Your lock isn't going to be on doWork; it's going to be on evictOldEntries.  There should be a way in Java to detect in doWork whether evictOldEntries has taken a lock.

Comment: I think you will want accesses to your cache to be mutually exclusive. You don't provide code for your `addIfMissing()` method but even that might be prone to race conditions if accesses to the cache's entries are not properly synchronized.

Comment: What I am doing inside the cache is actually invoking `clang` to compile a C/C++ source file to an `obj` file - which can take quite some time. I really don't want to synchronize the whole access to the cache.

Comment: Should `evictOldEntries()` be allowed to execute while other threads are executing `addIfMissing()`? If you want fine-grained synchronization, maybe you should look into `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of writing your own cache class.

Comment: @Eric no, I want other threads to wait until `evictOldEntries()` is done.

Comment: @JohnReese, yes, you want the other threads to wait until `evictOldEntries()` is done but it seems you also don't want to allow `evictOldEntries()` to execute while another thread is calling `addIfMissing()`, according to your comment on Robert Harvey's answer. So it seems that you need mutual exclusion, not just thread signaling. Coarse-grained locking on the entire cache is not acceptable but perhaps entry-level locking is?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is something like this:

```
class Cache {

    final ReentrantLock lock;

    public Cache { lock = new ReentrantLock(); }

    Entry addIfMissing(String data) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            // Add data here
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    void evictOldEntries() {
        if (lock.tryLock()) {
           try {
              // Evict old entries
           }
           finally {
              lock.unlock();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking a bit of liberty here since your code sample and exact requirements are a bit unclear. But might something like this work? `ConcurrentHashMap` uses fine-grained locking so you minimize the bottleneck when inserting entries into the cache. The evictor thread can even run concurrently with the inserting threads.

```
class Cache<String, CacheEntry> {
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, CacheEntry> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, CacheEntry>();

    Entry addIfMissing(String data) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(...);
    }

    void evictOldEntries() {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, CacheEntry>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            CacheEntry entry = iterator.next().getValue();

            if (shouldEvict(entry)) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `void evictOldEntries() { map.values().removeIf(entry -> shouldEvict(entry)); }`

Answer (score 1):

I think [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) is just what I need:

```java
class Program {
    private ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    void doWork() { // called from multiple threads
        rwl.readLock().lock();
        try {
            var entry = cache.addIfMissing("omitted for brevity");
            // work with entry
        } finally {
            rwl.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    static {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            rwl.writeLock().lock();
            try {
                cache.evictOldEntries();
            } finally {
                rwl.writeLock().unlock();
            }
        }, 10, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

This way once the writeLock is aquired `doWork` has to block and vice-versa.

Comment: How can you guarantee that writes to your cache in `doWork()` are properly synchronized?

Comment: I am using `ConcurrentHashMap` internally inside the Cache itself - I only need a way to mutually exclude `doWork()` and `evictOldEntries()`

Comment: Just curious why isn't the evictor thread not allowed to run concurrently with the other threads?

Comment: Essentially the Cache class is a registry of `java.nio.file.Path` objects of `.obj` files on the file system. If `.obj` files are removed, while new compiler processes are spawned, it might happen that the compilation fails.

Comment: The method name `addIfMissing` suggests that the method will modify the cache under certain conditions, so doing it when only owning a `readLock()` is incorrect.